# また、「たなら」と「るなら」についての質問です

Tags: grammar, tense, learning

> 親に頼めとか、お前がそこは立ち入ってくんだよ···
> 分かったよ、五万円だな、**必ず返すと○○○○**、まあ、**一度だけ貸してやっていいぞ**。

（A）必ず返すと約束**するなら**よ

（B）必ず返すと約束**したなら**よ

上のはネットで見た文です。この文ではAとＢどちらも使えますか？
詳しく教えていただけませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AとBどちらも使えます。ただ、個人的にはAのほうが自然です。

「なら」に限った話ではないですが、下記が原則になると思います（[ソース](https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/85028/gbkp_2020_j10_001.pdf)）。

P＝従属節のイベント、Q＝主節のイベント

[image]

現在の例の場合「貸してやっていい」は現在形なので、7b, 8b（右側の２つ）それぞれを見る形になり、

- Aの場合、P(約束) ≧Q(貸す/貸してもよい) ≧ 現在
- Bの場合 P < Q ≧ 現在

貸してから約束するということは（普通）ないので、Aの場合実質的には「P=Q」ということになり、「今約束するなら今貸す」というニュアンスになり、Bの場合は、「約束」が完了したら、というニュアンスが強くなります。

ただし、上だけではなぜAのほうが自然かについては説明できません。この点については個々の文によると思います。たとえば「約束したら守らなくてはいけない」という文であれば、「約束した」のほうが自然です。

Comment: sundownerさん、説明に長い文を書いてありがとうございます！ついでに聞いたいですが、Bの場合ではPと現在どちらがもっと前の話ですか？

Comment: また、Ｖ－ポイント、Ｖ－ポイントベースどういうことでしょうか。教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: googleで調べたら、こう書いてあります：
BASE  ：発話場としての現実スペースである「イマ・ココ・ワタシ」
V-POINT：発話場としての信念スペース内での観測点（及び観測基準）
信念とは精神面の自我だと考えれば良いですか？難解な言い方多くて理解しにくい

Comment: @JudyHarry V-POINTのほうはすいませんが、ソースのほうを見てください。

Comment: 多分ソースにもあると思いますが、基本的に従属節の動詞の時制は主節の動詞に対する相対時制です。そのため、PがQに対して前か後か、だけがPの時制を決定するため、現在との関係は不明です。

Comment: たとえば、「（あなたが）彼に会ったら伝えておいて」という文では「会った」は（タ形であるにもかかわらず）現在よりも先であることが想定されます。一方「彼に会ったなら伝えておいてくれればよかったのに」という文では「会った」は現在より以前です。

Comment: sundownerさん、本当に素晴らしい解説です！よく勉強しました！
sundownerさんの話はノートで記録しました。何度も教えてくれてありがとうございます！ご迷惑をおかけてすみませんでした。